# QR code link with multiple variables

Tags: php, qr-code

I have a bit of php that generates this image:

```
 $nome = strtoupper($_GET['nome']);
$email = $_GET['email'];
$tipo = strtoupper($_GET['tipo']);
$idade = strtoupper($_GET['idade']);
$atividades = strtoupper($_GET['atividades']);

echo "<img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.XXXXXXX.com%2Ffisica%2Fadd.php?nome=".$nome."&email=".$email."&tipo=".$tipo."&idade=".$idade."&atividades=".$atividades."' title='Apresenta este código na entrada.' />";
```

I need the QR to open a link with multiple variables and it just get the first. I think it's because it assumes that the other variables are QR generator link's vars.

I searched for this and nothing apeears me.

Can you help me?

Comment: Change `$_GET[nome]` to `$_GET['nome']`, `$_GET[email]` to `$_GET['email']` (Same with all the other `$_GET` variables.

Comment: Sure, but the issue is on the "echo" line.

Comment: what does the `src` value look like when you echo just that?

Comment: @Matt that isn't actually a problem, more a "best practice" guideline. It's still compatible to handle legacy code - [see example](https://eval.in/523428)

Comment: @RobbieAverill I know it's not the issue, hence why it wasn't posted as an answer, just a suggestion.

Comment: The src shows this: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.XXXXXXX.com%2Ffisica%2Fadd.php?nome=".$nome."
Because if I write another '&' it assumes that the next value is a QR parameter and not a (my) link's variable.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using PHP's [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function. Also, you can embed variables in a double-quoted string, and you should be escaping ampersands as `&amp;` before output to HTML.

```
$nome = strtoupper($_GET['nome']);
$email = $_GET['email'];
$tipo = strtoupper($_GET['tipo']);
$idade = strtoupper($_GET['idade']);
$atividades = strtoupper($_GET['atividades']);
$url = "http://www.XXXXXXX.com/fisica/add.php?nome=$nome&email=$email&tipo=$tipo&idade=$idade&atividades=$atividades";
$url = urlencode($url);

echo "<img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&amp;cht=qr&amp;chl=$url' title='Apresenta este código na entrada' />";
```